# Correct the equation by moving $1$ match stick

Tags: matches

[image]

Since $23$ and $7$ both are primes, so I am try to make $23$ to $14$ by moving only one match stick. But I am unable to do this. Any hints will be appreciated. Here note that the line divided by denominator and numerator is also made with three matchstick.

I am new in puzzling stackexchange. So I am sorry if the the problem is trivial and if it is required to add any tag or change please edit the question.

Comment: Sometimes the "trick" to these is just using one matchstick to make `≠`. Is that against the rules?

Comment: I don't know. I saw the problem in school's puzzle book. But I am understood your  trick.

Comment: Is taking one stick off the second X too simple?

Answer (score 30):

Maybe not the answer, but it is so sexy it probably is:

> move 1 match from the XXIII (23) and put it on top of the II (2) to make the famous Mathematical coincidence that 22/7 is roughly equal to Pi (π)

Comment: https://www.bhavinionline.com/2016/05/correct-equation-just-moving-1-matchstick-xxiiivii-ii/ - was about to post this

Comment: Upvote for being so sexy

Comment: It's not that much of a "coincidence". The difference is one part in 2500. There are 1000 different ways to divide a 2 digit number by a 1 digit number.

Comment: This is actually the first thing I thought of, except that OP wants 14. I feel like this is the intended solution, though.

Comment: While this may be the intended answer, it's not a correct answer, as $22/7 = \pi$ is NOT a correct statement, and hence doesn't "correct" the equation at all.

Answer (score 10):

Is this cheating?

> [image: Possible solution]
>  Take the second match on the RHS, break it in 3 pieces, and create three minus signs.

Comment: I consider this perfectly within the confines of the rules defined and a much better solution than the top voted pi non-equation.

Answer (score 8):

A possibility, depending on how you interpret an arrangement of matchsticks:

> The actual arrangement is here:
>  [image]
>  
>  Parts of this layout are, um, ambiguous, to say the least. Here's how I would interpret the layout (without *actually* moving the other matchsticks):
>  [image]

Converting this equation to MathJax, we have:

> $$ \frac{10}{5} \times \frac{3}{2} = 3 $$
>  $$ 2 \times \frac{3}{2} = 3 $$
>  $$ 3 = 3 $$

Answer (score 3):

If a sloppy-looking and technically-written-wrong answer is allowed, you could

> Move one matchstick from the second X in XXIII to join the line of division, producing XIIII/VII=II

But,

> The division line looks sloppy (unless you lay the match on top, in 3D space, of one of the existing matches?), the first I in XIIII is slanted, and XIIII is not a technically correct roman numeral (it should instead be written as XIV)

Comment: Nothing says you can't move the one matchstick completely out of the puzzle. Of course, at that rate, nothing says you can't move a matchstick that's not in the puzzle now into it....

Answer (score 2):

> Make the denominator into XII. Everybody knows $\frac{23}{12}=2$.

Comment: Quick maths xD.

Comment: Actually thats not true, 24/12 = 2

Comment: I think JonMark Perry forgot to say "...for sufficiently small values of 12 and 2".

Comment: $23/12\approx 2$, because the answer is $22/7\approx\pi$, so my guess is good...

Answer (score 2):

ok a bit convoluted but how about....

[image]

on the bottom IX = 9 so maybe IXII = 11

rather convoluted and not as good as some of the other answers, but worth a try....

and as pointed out in the comment below the number on the bottom could be |XI|- the modulus of 11....

Comment: `IXII = 11` Request Denied.

Comment: Wait, on second thought - instead of reading that as 9+2 as you implied, we could read that as the absolute value of XI. Close, but the left stick is too bent though `\XI|`. Hmm, unsatisfactory, but provisionally approved pending appeal.

Comment: @AmitNaidu - great idea! I will edit